# Heroku pg:backups:restore failed with postgis extension

Tags: heroku, postgis, heroku-postgres

I am following this [set of instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#create-dump-file) provided by Heroku to export a copy of my local postgis database and restore it to my Heroku postgres instance. I further followed this [set of instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search#installing-extensions) to provision the postgis extension for my database on Heroku.

The provisioning worked as expected.

```
climbville::DATABASE=> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
climbville::DATABASE=> \dx
                                List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                        Description                         
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis | 3.2.3   | heroku_ext | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions
```

I then ran the restore using the following command:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore '<presigned url>' DATABASE_URL --app climbville
```

However, the restore failed with the following error message:

```
pg_restore: creating EXTENSION "postgis"
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 2; 3079 18546 EXTENSION postgis (no owner)
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  Extensions can only be created on heroku_ext schema
```

The restore seems to be failing when it checks for and tries to install the postgis extension.  I noticed that when I logged into the Heroku postgres instance after the attenmpted resotre, the postgis extension was gone.  This leads me to believe that the pg:restore deleted the extension and then tried to reinstall it but failed.

Any ideas how I can install the postgis extension on my Heroku postgres instance at the time of restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have discovered how to fix the above issue. Instead of using the above restore command, I added `--extensions 'postgis'` to the command.  That is:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore '<presigned url>' DATABASE_URL --extensions 'postgis' --app climbville
```

According to this [support post](https://help.heroku.com/ZOFBHJCJ/heroku-postgres-extension-changes-faq) from Heroku, they changed how the postgis extension is stored in the database, and it seems the `--extensions` flag correctly adds the extension prior to the restore.

Comment: This modifies the production database